# Setting Alerting configuration on Kibana 7.9

Tags: elasticsearch, action, alert, kibana-7, elasticsearch-x-pack

I am using basic license for elastic search with on-premises deployment without security.
I want to get started with Alerting and Actions in Kibana 7.9.
I have set `xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey` value as per documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.9/alert-action-settings-kb.html#general-alert-action-settings)

I restarted kibana after adding encrytionKey in kibana.yml file.

Still I am getting the same error as “You must set an encryption key”

[image]

Any leads will be appreciated.

And after kibana was restarted, it just crashed. needed to revert kibana.yml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution as discussed [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/setting-alerting-configuration-on-kibana-7-9/250530/10)

Restarted `elasticsearch` and `kibana` - both services after adding `encryptionKey` in `kibana.yml`.

Answer (score 5):

1. `bin/kibana-encryption-keys.bat generate`
2. copy your information

   `xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

   `xpack.reporting.encryptionKey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

   `xpack.security.encryptionKey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
3. paste in your `kibana.yml`
4. reset `ElasticSearch` and `Kibana`
5. done

Comment: we can setup alert using free version?